# How to use do in lisp?

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

What I'm trying to do is to write a function that which will restart a game of tic-tac-toe after it ends.
What is supposed to happen is that the player will be asked if they want to play another game. If they do, then they click yes and a function is called that will start the game over. If they choose no, then the program terminates.
Here is what i have so far...

```
(defun play-again ()
  (do (y-or-n-p "Would you like to play again? ")
      ((play-one-game) nil)))
```

The play-one-game is the function that i want to run if the user clicks"yes" from the prompt. Otherwise the game terminates since no other function is called. By the way, just in case you need to know, i am using Allegro.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_do_do.htm)?

Comment: What doesn't work about your code?  Do you get an error?  Does it run, but doesn't do what you expect it to?  Which part of the specification of [DO](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_do_do.htm) do you have a question about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `y-or-n-p` nil only when the user pressed n you could write your main loop as

```
(defun main ()
  (loop :while (y-or-n-p "Would you like to play again? ")
        :do (play-one-game)))
```

or at the end of play-one-game, which I would rename play, prompt the user and if he wants to play again just call play one more time.

```
(defun play-one-game ()
  ....
  (when (y-or-n-p "Would you like to play again? ")
    (play-one-game)))
```

Comment: The last one will eventually blow the stack in some implementations.

Comment: Most Common Lisp implementations do TCO though, and Allegro certainly does: http://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand a form in CL you should read in the CLHS (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_do_do.htm)

Here a solution using do:
    (defun play-again ()
      (do ((again t (y-or-n-p "Would you like to play again? ")))
          ((not again) nil)
        (play-one-game)))

(this function calls `play-one-game` the first time without a question)